# На Android 4.2.2 меню в ActionBar (три точки) не отображается

Tags: android, actionbar, android-menu

Недавно обнаружил, что пропала кнопка меню (три точки). Меню конечно есть, если нажать на хардварную кнопку, но это совсем не дело.
Меню создаю внутри кода

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add(0, MENU_EXIT, 100, getResources().getString(R.string.menuExit));
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Меню располагается в ActionBar, который немного переопределен в style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item></style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
<item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_background</item></style>
```

Где я накосячил?
P.S. Где то читал даже, что если в смартфоне есть хардварная кнопка Меню, то три точки отображаться не будут... (можно ли тут давать ссылки, но читал про это тут: https://toster.ru/q/213321)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно в onCreate() Activity вписать вот этот код:

```
        try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // Ignore
    }
```

Решение найдено здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button/11438245#11438245